# Non-null column after using acts as paranoid gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-paranoid

I have been using the Acts as Paranoid gem and now I have a bunch of Users that have been soft deleted.  I am trying to add a non-null column but I keep getting errors because those soft-deleted records have a null value and I cannot update them.  How can I handle this?

Here's the migration I'm trying to run:

```
 def change
    add_column :users, :jti, :string

    # Does not include soft-deleted records
    User.all.each { |user| user.update_column(:jti, SecureRandom.uuid) }

    missing_jti = User.with_deleted.where(jti: nil)
    p "Users missing jti: #{missing_jti.count}" # NOT 0

    change_column_null :users, :jti, false # throws error due to soft-deleted records containing null jti
  end
```

When I attempt to update the soft-deleted records, I get an error:

```
User.with_deleted.each { |user| user.update_column(:jti, SecureRandom.uuid) }
ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError: cannot update a destroyed record
```

Comment: how about run a pure sql to update instead of using ActiveRecord ?

Comment: That's a great idea!

Comment: https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid/issues/45